# Python3 - How do I stop current versions of packages being over-ridden by other packages dependencies

Tags: python, pip, package-managers

Building Tensorflow and other such packages from source and especially against GPU's is a fairly long task and often encounters errors, so once built and installed I really dont want to mess with them.

I regularly use virtualenvs, but I am always worried about installing certain packages as sometimes their dependencies will overwrite my own packages I have built from source...

I know I can remove, and then rebuild from my .wheels, but sometimes this is a time consuming task. Is there a way that if I attempt to pip install a package, it first checks against current package versions and doesn't continue before I agree to those changes? 
Even current packages dependencies don't show versions with `pip show`

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way that if I attempt to pip install a package, it first checks against current package versions and doesn't continue before I agree to those changes?

No. But `pip install` doesn't touch installed dependencies until you explicitly run `pip install -U`. So don't use `-U/--upgrade` option and upgrade dependencies when `pip` fails with unmet dependencies.